# Why am I seeing this advertisement when I have the Reduce Ads Privilege?

Tags: support, advertising

Here in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads.  They told us that when you get 200+ reputation then ads will be reduced. 
But ads are still appearing in my profile.

I always get so many ads. So what is the reason behind it?

[image]

Comment: That is an ad from SE network - you won't lose those ads.  I get those too.

Comment: "As a courtesy to our avid users, we automatically disable __some__ ads when they reach this reputation level."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the privilege is **reduced** ads, not **zero** ads.

The page has three ads - you are only seeing one.

The [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) even says so - and if you read through it and look at the first image, you will see you are not getting ads in the spots where the red rectangles are.

From the article:

> The areas in red are the leaderboard ads. The areas in gray are the sidebar ads, which will remain visible.